# How to fix iOS 7 status bar height and width issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

I have made a custom toast library (very simple, just a box which appears under navigation bar). Which works fine in iOS 6 which is my target group. But since iOS 7 has released it didn't display correctly.

The way I tried to fix it was through this code:

```
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7,0")){
    self.offset = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height + self.viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
}
```

I made a macro which can be found on Stack overflow to detect if the iOS version is 7 and then add the status bar height and the navigation height. This works correctly in portrait mode in iOS 7, but when I switch to landscape offset becomes 512?.

Can anybody explain way this happens and how I can fix this?

---

Decided to split the code because a comment and see what is exactly causing the difference. What I did was:

CGFloat statusBarHeight =[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

```
CGFloat navBar = self.viewController.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
self.offset = statusBarHeight + navBar;
NSLog(@"Init - statusBarHeight: %f, navBar: %f", statusBarHeight, navBar);
```

As it turns out for some reason statusbar is in portrait  20 and in landscape it is 480

---

This is because height and width are turned around, answer came from comment

Comment: My guess is that in landscape  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width and  [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height values are switched

Comment: This is true, thanks if you can post your answer I can accept it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I have previously done same "fixes", I've noticed that in landscape

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width
```

and

```
 [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

values are switched.

Comment: This answer does not work with iOS 8, which correctly reports the status bar's height.

Answer (score 7):

Travis Jeffery provided an excellent explanation on
http://travisjeffery.com/b/2013/05/using-the-status-bars-frame-in-ios/

Let me copy it from his site:

"The trick to the status bar’s frame and height is to make sure you’ve converted it to the coordinate space of the view that you care about, this will probably be a UIViewController’s view or subview."

```
CGRect statusBarFrame = [yourView.window convertRect:UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame toView:yourView];
CGFloat statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to use the View Controller's `topLayoutGuide.length` which should correspond to the status bar's height.